Kotlin multiplatform wizard build generates a build with an error in Ios for me
Platform.kt
MainViewController
I have already made multiplatform projects for desktop and web, everything was fine. I wanted to make an application for ios and android, everything is fine with android, but in ios there is an error in every file in the iosMain folder.  I didn't change anything, just downloaded the build from the official site and that's all.
I think the problem may be related to the development environment, but I already tried reinstalling, it didn't help. Here is the gradle code, maybe it will help to figure it out:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "org.talent"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "org.talent"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
    }
}


what error is it? you can see build output in Xcode in Report navigator tab. you're on macOS, right?

I'm on windows, but in all the tutorials, no one has the error. I didn't pay attention to it for a long time, but now I need to write code related to storing data on the device, and for this I need to write separate code for Ios, but for example I can't even use NSUserDefaults, because it's like it's not in my project, although it should be by default

you can't build or even get code suggestions for iOS app development from windows, it's only possible from macOS - it requires Xcode to be installed

To write iOS-related code and get the hint, you need to have x Code installed, which is only available on an Apple machine. If you are trying it on Windows, you will never be able to, it is an Apple requirement. If you are in X code, please share the error so I can help you
